# Postfix sends every mail twice

Tags: postfix

Could someone please tell me, why Postfix sends each message twice?

I noticed that one message is correctly send and the other may (or may not) have a problem with the encoding.

To be honest I did some adjustments for virtual domains, users,.... but I cannot find why these configurations should not work.

I have the slight feeling it has something to do with virtual users, but I could also be wrong!

**EDIT** added postconf -n results

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = reco-server.mydomain, localhost.mydomain,  localhost
myhostname = reco-server.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, \   reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_client, \   reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org , \   smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_address, \   reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_limit = 250
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,\    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

**ALSO**: from the log:

```
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/pickup[8660]: 1B404C35A7: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/cleanup[9388]: 1B404C35A7: message-id=<b3a040c51775e77d08642080424ae61e@localhost>
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/qmgr[7727]: 1B404C35A7: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=7659, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/pickup[8660]: 2978EC35A6: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/cleanup[9388]: 2978EC35A6: message-id=<125112410529d73e1c2484cf9c991064@localhost>
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/qmgr[7727]: 2978EC35A6: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=1064, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/smtp[9396]: 2978EC35A6: lost connection with mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.139.54.60] while receiving the initial server greeting
Nov 12 12:18:20 reco-server postfix/smtp[9396]: 2978EC35A6: to=<recipient@yahoo.com>, relay=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.217.202]:25, delay=4, delays=0.09/0.01/0.92/3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Nov 12 12:18:20 reco-server postfix/qmgr[7727]: 2978EC35A6: removed
Nov 12 12:18:20 reco-server postfix/smtp[9394]: 1B404C35A7: to=<recipient@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.139.54.60]:25, delay=4.2, delays=0.19/0.01/0.55/3.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Nov 12 12:18:20 reco-server postfix/qmgr[7727]: 1B404C35A7: removed
```

Comment: A sample from your mail log including a message being sent twice would be useful.

Comment: Please provide evidence (i.e. a log excerpt demonstrating the problem) as well as the output of `postconf -n`.

Comment: Is the added text helpful?

Comment: Can you show us where 1B404C35A7 comes in (output of grep 1B404C35A7 $maillog will do)

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Edited the bottom part of the log. Is this OK?

Comment: Those two mails are not the same: the size differs significantly. SO something is making your webserver send 2 mails simultaneously. I'd look at the (webmail?) software you use and inspect its log. Postfix seems to be doing its job right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/pickup[8660]: 1B404C35A7: uid=33 from=<www-data>

Nov 12 12:18:16 reco-server postfix/pickup[8660]: 2978EC35A6: uid=33 from=<www-data>
```

Two distinct Queue-IDs indicates that two distinct messages were submitted to postfix; this is caused by your web server process, not postfix.

Comment: Emmm, to be honest i don't understand what this means. Having now tested the command line mail i confirm your observation (i used phplist, which is web-based, to send an email). But now i am more confused: is it a matter of phplist or is it a matter of Apache?

Comment: Apache doesn't send any mail, ever. It is your php application.

Comment: YES!! you're right! i feel so dumb!!! Thanks to your observation i took a good look in phplist where i found the following setting: define('SEND_ONE_TESTMAIL',0); which means: if phplist is about to send a TEST mail, should it send only ONE!!?? My setting was 0, meaning: NO please send TWO!!! Thanks very much!!